# How to split columns into 2

Tags: tables, two-column, split

I want the first row to stay normal and then every row after that should be split into 2 columns. I've done it on Microsoft word to show exactly what I want. I tried used multicolumn but couldn't get it to work correctly.

[image: Table]

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c| } 
    \hline
    B    & B 1 & B 2 & B3 & B4 & B5 & B6 & B 7 \\
    \hline
    1   & 12 & 12 & 12 & 12 &12  &12& 12\\ 
    \hline
    2   & 12& 12& 12& 12&12& 12& 12\\ 
    \hline
    3   & & & & & & & \\ 
    \hline
    4   & & & & & & &\\ 
    \hline
    5   & & & & & & &\\ 
    \hline
    6   & & & & & & & \\ 
    \hline
    7   & & & & & & &\\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! cells you can merge, but not divide. for your cell with `x` you can obtain with `\multicolumn{2}{c}{x}`. similar for others.

Comment: Thanks Zarko, apologies but its my first time creating a table on latex so still a little confused. I tried doing that but it came up with an error. I've updated the question with what I have so far.

Comment: You might take a look at the [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) for an overview about tables in LaTeX. Also consider using the [`booktabs`](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package and following the guidelines laid out in the documentation of `booktabs` for prettier tables.

Comment: to see your table in context, we need to see complete but small document beginning with`\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. about tables beside what suggest @Skillmon, see https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- your table code fragment doesn't reproduce showed table. for this it ha defined one column less as needed (you have defined only 8 columns, but showed table has 9)
- for help to people who like to help you, y\documentclass{...} and ending with `\end{document}, which show your problem. it should have in preamble loaded all to your problem relevant packages (if any needed)
- as i mentioned in comment, cells cant be split, but can be merged. so solution in general in your case is use command `\multicolumn{2}{c}{...}` which merge tvo columns and cell's content align in its middle.
- without knowing content of your table your code snippet can be converted into mwe as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| *{9}{c|} }
    \hline
B    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{x}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{z}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{w}
                            & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{t}                \\
    \hline
1   &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  \\
    \hline
2   &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  \\
    \hline
3   &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- however, your table can be written on many diferent way. one of them is use`booktabs` packages for horizontal rules where needed, omit vertical riles and for example use modified `X` columns from package `tabularx:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c *{8}{C} }
    \toprule
B    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{x}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{z}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{w}
                            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{t}                \\
    \midrule
1   &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  \\
2   &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  &   12  \\
3   &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh yes I see what I was doing wrong. Thanks and for the future tips, I'll be sure too use them next time when asking a question.

Comment: can we have second layer for labels on top of `12` `12`  as well?

Comment: @alper, sorry, I do not understand your comment. Do you like to have one more row above tale body? Just insert it. But, I suggest you, ask new question where describe what you like change in above table (BTW, today I would use `tabularray` package in their writing).

Comment: I was lookling something like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174328/127048 ; like having exta label for each 12 below `B x z w t`

Comment: @alper, you can do this on the same way as is done in answer in your link. If you need additional/specific support, at this, than please ask new question that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=.45in,right=.45in,top=.6in,bottom=.6in,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,multirow,textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

 %    \setlength\extrarowheight{32pt}
\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}|C{1cm}}
    \hline
 x & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{y}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{z} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{w}& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{t}\\ \hline
 1 &&&&&&&&\\ \hline
 2 &&&&&&&&\\ \hline
 3  &&&&&&&&\\ \hline
 4  &&&&&&&&\\ \hline
 5  &&&&&&&&\\ \hline
 6  &&&&&&&&\\   \hline     
 7  &&&&&&&&\\ \hline


\end{tabular}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\cline{1-9}` instead of a `\hline`? And why are you using `C` column specifiers? It doesn't seem necessary here.

Comment: In the example, you define a `C` column twice. You as well load the `array` package twice and included some packages that are not needed (`multirow`,`textcomp`) to produce the table.