# How to create a table with multiple columns?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I'm new to the latex world. Is there a way to produce a table like the following?

[image]

I've tried with the following code exploiting `multirow`, `siunitx` and `booktabs` packages following this reference https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174328/233121 but the result is not really the expected one.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  *{6}{S[table-format=1.4]}
  S[table-format=5]
  S[table-format=3.2]
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Program}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Problem Size}} &
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Instructions (Billions)}}  &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Synchronization Primitives}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-9}
&& {\textbf{Total}} & {\textbf{FLOPS}} & {\textbf{Reads}} & {\textbf{Writes}} & {\textbf{Locks}} & {\textbf{Barriers}} & {\textbf{Conditions}} \\
\midrule
\texttt{blackscholes}  & 65,536 options & 2.67 & 1.14 & 0.68 & 0.19 & 0 & 8 & 0 \\
\texttt{freqmine} & 990,000 transactions & 33.45 & 0.00 & 11.31 & 5.24 & 990,025 & 0 & 0 \\
\texttt{swaptions}  & 64 swaptions, 20,000 simulations & 14.11 & 2.62 & 5.08 & 1.16 & 23 & 0 & 0 \\
\texttt{bodytrack} & 4 frames, 4,000 particles & 14.03 & 4.22 & 3.63 & 0.95 & 114,621 & 619 & 2,042 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to find a solution in order to automatically wrap overfulling text but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do that table (in landscape mode because, otherwise, it's too wide).

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ll*{5}{S}S[table-format=4.0]S}[hvlines]
\Block{2-1}{\textbf{Program}} &
\Block{2-1}{\textbf{Problem Size}} &
{\Block{1-4}{\textbf{Instructions (Billions)}}}  &&&&
{\Block{1-3}{\textbf{Synchronization Primitives}}} \\
&& {\textbf{Total}} & {\textbf{FLOPS}} & {\textbf{Reads}} & {\textbf{Writes}} & {\textbf{Locks}} & {\textbf{Barriers}} & {\textbf{Conditions}} \\
\texttt{blackscholes}  & 65,536 options & 2.67 & 1.14 & 0.68 & 0.19 & 0 & 8 & 0 \\
\texttt{freqmine} & 990,000 transactions & 33.45 & 0.00 & 11.31 & 5.24 & 990,025 & 0 & 0 \\
\texttt{swaptions}  & 64 swaptions, 20,000 simulations & 14.11 & 2.62 & 5.08 & 1.16 & 23 & 0 & 0 \\
\texttt{bodytrack} & 4 frames, 4,000 particles & 14.03 & 4.22 & 3.63 & 0.95 & 114,621 & 619 & 2,042 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the first code]

The output is certainly better with only the horizontal rules provided by `bookmarks`:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}ll*{5}{S}S[table-format=4.0]S@{}}
\toprule
\Block{2-1}{\textbf{Program}} &
\Block{2-1}{\textbf{Problem Size}} &
{\Block{1-4}{\textbf{Instructions (Billions)}}}  &&&&
{\Block{1-3}{\textbf{Synchronization Primitives}}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-6} \cmidrule(l){7-9}
&& {\textbf{Total}} & {\textbf{FLOPS}} & {\textbf{Reads}} & {\textbf{Writes}} & {\textbf{Locks}} &
{\textbf{Barriers}} & {\textbf{Conditions}} \\
\midrule
\texttt{blackscholes}  & 65,536 options & 2.67 & 1.14 & 0.68 & 0.19 & 0 & 8 & 0 \\
\texttt{freqmine} & 990,000 transactions & 33.45 & 0.00 & 11.31 & 5.24 & 990,025 & 0 & 0 \\
\texttt{swaptions}  & 64 swaptions, 20,000 simulations & 14.11 & 2.62 & 5.08 & 1.16 & 23 & 0 & 0 \\
\texttt{bodytrack} & 4 frames, 4,000 particles & 14.03 & 4.22 & 3.63 & 0.95 & 114,621 & 619 & 2,042 \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: I like both your solutions! Unfortunately I'm currently working on my thesis and I'm obliged to work with this format `\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright,english,italian]{book}`. Do you think there is a workaround to fit the table?

Comment: I would rotate th tabular by 90° (`\rotatebox{90}{...}`) and let LaTeX puts the table as it usually does for all the floats.

Answer (score 0):

- Your table is to wide that can be fit in on page's text area
- as possible solutions enabling split text in the second column into multi lines
- also will help use smaller font and reduce size of the `\tabcolsep`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright,english,italian]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}  % added
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, 
            tabularx} % added 
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} 
  l L
    S[table-format=2.2]
    S[table-format=1.2]
    S[table-format=2.2]
    S[table-format=1.2]
%
    S[table-format=3.3]
    S[table-format=3.0]
    S[table-format=1.3]
                @{}}
    \toprule
\textbf{Program}    
    & \textbf{Problem Size}
        & \mcc[4]{\textbf{Instructions (Billions)}}  
            & \mcc[3]{\textbf{Synchronization Primitives}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-9}
    &   & {\textbf{Total}} 
            & {\textbf{FLOPS}} 
                & {\textbf{Reads}} 
                    & {\textbf{Writes}} 
                        & {\textbf{Locks}} 
                            & {\textbf{Barriers}} 
                                & {\textbf{Conditions}} \\
\midrule
\texttt{blackscholes}  & 65,536 options & 2.67 & 1.14 & 0.68 & 0.19 & 0 & 8 & 0 \\
\texttt{freqmine} & 990,000 transactions & 33.45 & 0.00 & 11.31 & 5.24 & 990,025 & 0 & 0 \\
\texttt{swaptions}  & 64 swaptions, 20,000 simulations & 14.11 & 2.62 & 5.08 & 1.16 & 23 & 0 & 0 \\
\texttt{bodytrack} & 4 frames, 4,000 particles & 14.03 & 4.22 & 3.63 & 0.95 & 114,621 & 619 & 2,042 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*addendum:*
small variation where for `X` column is used `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` and enlarge table stretch:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright,english,italian]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
    \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} 
  l L
    S[table-format=2.2]
    S[table-format=1.2]
    S[table-format=2.2]
    S[table-format=1.2]
%
    S[table-format=3.3]
    S[table-format=3.0]
    S[table-format=1.3]
                @{}}
    \toprule
\textbf{Program}    
    & \textbf{Problem Size}
        & \mcc[4]{\textbf{Instructions (Billions)}}  
            & \mcc[3]{\textbf{Synchronization Primitives}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-9}
    &   & {\textbf{Total}} 
            & {\textbf{FLOPS}} 
                & {\textbf{Reads}} 
                    & {\textbf{Writes}} 
                        & {\textbf{Locks}} 
                            & {\textbf{Barriers}} 
                                & {\textbf{Conditions}} \\
    \midrule
\texttt{blackscholes}  & 65,536 options & 2.67 & 1.14 & 0.68 & 0.19 & 0 & 8 & 0 \\
\texttt{freqmine} & 990,000 transactions & 33.45 & 0.00 & 11.31 & 5.24 & 990,025 & 0 & 0 \\
\texttt{swaptions}  & 64 swaptions, \newline
                      20,000 simulations & 14.11 & 2.62 & 5.08 & 1.16 & 23 & 0 & 0 \\
\texttt{bodytrack} & 4 frames, \newline
                     4,000 particles & 14.03 & 4.22 & 3.63 & 0.95 & 114,621 & 619 & 2,042 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]