# How can I have white column line in a table?

Tags: tables, color, line

In a table, I have rows represented as gray and white colors using `\rowcolors{3}{}{gray!20}`. Here, I want to split columns using white color line instead of black. The way I created column lines using `|` but I cannot define its color.

Example is take from [Table with multiple columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174328/127048), with small changes I made.

> ````tex
> \usepackage{booktabs} \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
>
> \begin{document} \begin{table}[htp]
>     \centering
>     \rowcolors{3}{gray!20}{}
>     \begin{tabular}{
>       l|
>       *{3}{S[table-format=1.4]}|
>       *{3}{S[table-format=1.4]}
>       S[table-format=5]
>       }
>       \toprule
>       \multicolumn{1}{c}{Data Set}       &
>       \multicolumn{3}{c}{Balanced Error} &
>       \multicolumn{3}{c}{Area Under Curve}                                                         \\
>       \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
>                                          & {Train} & {Valid} & {Test} & {Train} & {Valid} & {Test} \\
>       \midrule
>       arcene                             & 0.5000  & 0.4886  & 0.5006 & 0.5000  & 0.5114  & 0.4994 \\
>       gisette                            & 0.5000  & 0.4886  & 0.5006 & 0.5000  & 0.5114  & 0.4994 \\
>       dexter                             & 0.5000  & 0.4886  & 0.5006 & 0.5000  & 0.5114  & 0.4994 \\
>       madelon                            & 0.5000  & 0.4886  & 0.5006 & 0.5000  & 0.5114  & 0.4994 \\
>       \bottomrule
>     \end{tabular} \end{table} \end{document} ```
> ````

output:

[image]

Instead the the drawning column line (`|`) black, can it be white, example output would be:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use `!{\color{white}\vrule}` as provided by the `colortbl` package (which is loaded by `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \rowcolors{3}{gray!20}{}
    \begin{tabular}{
      l!{\color{white}\vrule}
      *{3}{S[table-format=1.4]}!{\color{white}\vrule}
      *{3}{S[table-format=1.4]}
      S[table-format=5]
      }
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{Data Set}       &
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{Balanced Error} &
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{Area Under Curve}                                                         \\
      \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
                                         & {Train} & {Valid} & {Test} & {Train} & {Valid} & {Test} \\
      \midrule
      arcene                             & 0.5000  & 0.4886  & 0.5006 & 0.5000  & 0.5114  & 0.4994 \\
      gisette                            & 0.5000  & 0.4886  & 0.5006 & 0.5000  & 0.5114  & 0.4994 \\
      dexter                             & 0.5000  & 0.4886  & 0.5006 & 0.5000  & 0.5114  & 0.4994 \\
      madelon                            & 0.5000  & 0.4886  & 0.5006 & 0.5000  & 0.5114  & 0.4994 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to shift the rule in x-axis? For example if `Balanced Error` is long string like `Balanced Error Balanced Error` and when I try to draw ruler in between Train in Valid columns, it does not show up in the middle

Comment: Please note that `\color{white}\vrule` is *not* provided by `colortbl`, this is possible using `array` and `color` (both of which are loaded by `colortbl`).

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly easy to achieve with [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray)

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx,booktabs}
 
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {
      l
      *{3}{S[table-format=1.4]}
      *{3}{S[table-format=1.4]}
    },
    row{odd} = {bg=gray!10},
    row{1} = {bg=white},
    hline{2} = {2-4}{leftpos=-1,rightpos=-1,endpos,\cmidrulewidth},
    hline{2} = {5-7}{leftpos=-1,rightpos=-1,endpos,\cmidrulewidth},
    vline{2,5} = {3-Z}{fg=white,1.2pt},
  }
  \toprule
  Data Set
  & \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{Balanced Error}}} &&
  & \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{Area Under Curve}}} && \\
  & {{{Train}}} & {{{Valid}}} & {{{Test}}} & {{{Train}}} & {{{Valid}}} & {{{Test}}} \\
  \midrule
  arcene   & 0.5000  & 0.4886  & 0.5006 & 0.5000  & 0.5114  & 0.4994 \\
  gisette  & 0.5000  & 0.4886  & 0.5006 & 0.5000  & 0.5114  & 0.4994 \\
  dexter   & 0.5000  & 0.4886  & 0.5006 & 0.5000  & 0.5114  & 0.4994 \\
  madelon  & 0.5000  & 0.4886  & 0.5006 & 0.5000  & 0.5114  & 0.4994 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```